# Problemas de concatenación en mi cadena de sentencia sql en archivo properties en java

Tags: java, sql, oracle-18c, spring-jdbc, jdbc-template

Hola buenas noches amigos, espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que tengo un método donde se ejecuta una sentencia desde java en un archivo properties, estoy trabajando con spring jdbc template;

```
// Metodo para actualizar los sobrepagos como pagos Normales//JJ
    public int actualizaSobrepagoCompPago(String region, String series) throws CPagoException {
        int resultado;
        try {
            JdbcTemplate jdbcT = conexionRegion(region);
            LOGGER.info("Inicia actualizacion de registros de sobrepago complementos pagos");
            LOGGER.info("ConexionSerie JJ..." + series);
            resultado = jdbcT.update(getQueryMapper().getActualizaSobrePagosCompPago().toString(),new Object [] {series});
            LOGGER.info("Que trae series..." + series);
            if (resultado == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("No hubo actualización");
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Termina actualizacion de " + resultado
                        + " registros en sobrepago a pago (tipo doc 4 a 1, id_estatus a 1 y serie a null)");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CPagoException(e);
        }
        return resultado;

    }

,new Object [] {series}--Esta linea se encarga de pasarle lo que traiga mi objeto de `seríes`
```

Que regresa de este metodo:

```
public String cadenasRegionesAprocesarUpdate() throws CPagoException {// JJ
        String capturaRegiones = "";
        String cadenaRegiones = "";
        String capturaSerie = "";
        String separador = ",";
        // String cadenaSerieCompleta="";
        try {
            LOGGER.info("Consulta region a procesar de tabla Parametros JJ <<<<<-----");
            List<ParametrosVO> listRegion = jdbcTPARAM.query(
                    getQueryMapper().getQueryConsultaRegionProcesar().toString(), new ParametrosMapper<ParametrosVO>());
            for (ParametrosVO parametrosVO : listRegion) {
                capturaRegiones = parametrosVO.getValor();
            }

            cadenaRegiones = capturaRegiones;
            LOGGER.info("cadenaRegiones..." + cadenaRegiones.toString());
            String[] arrayRegiones = cadenaRegiones.split(",");

            for (String numeroRegion : arrayRegiones) {
                capturaSerie += "'" + capturaNumeroRegion(numeroRegion) + "'" + separador;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new CPagoException(e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("capturaSerie..," + capturaSerie.toString());
        return capturaSerie.replaceAll(",$", "");// Quita comas al final JJ
    }
```

Este es el metodo que ejecuta mi update en base a los metodos de arriba:

```
public class ProcesoActualizaSobrePagoCp  extends QuartzJobBean implements StatefulJob {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ProcesoActualizaSobrePagoCp.class);

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        LOGGER.info("Inciando Proceso de Actualizacion SobrePagos prueba");     
        ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) jobExecContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("context");
        CPagoRepositoryImpl cPagoRepository = (CPagoRepositoryImpl) context.getBean("CPagoRepositoryImpl");
        EmailMapper emailMapper = (EmailMapper)  context.getBean("emailMapper");
        //List<String> listaRegiones = Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9");
//      try {
//          for(String regiones: listaRegiones) {
//              cPagoRepository.actualizaSobrepagoCompPago(regiones);
//              LOGGER.info("Recorrí..." + regiones);
//          }
//          
//      } catch (CPagoException e) {
//          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }
        try {
            //String capturanumeroR ="";
            String region =cPagoRepository.procesaRegion();//jj  
            //1,2
            String series = cPagoRepository.cadenasRegionesAprocesarUpdate();//Regresa las series   
            //'PA','PB'
            LOGGER.info("Que trae Region Desde clase ProcesoActualizaSobrePagoCp..."+ region);
            LOGGER.info("Que trae Region Desde clase ProcesoActualizaSobrePagoCp......"+ series);
            
            String[] arrayRegiones = region.split(",");
            LOGGER.info("Que trae arrayRegiones Antes del for..."+ arrayRegiones.toString());
            for (String regiones : arrayRegiones) {
                LOGGER.info("Que trae Regiones..."+ regiones.toString());
                LOGGER.info("Que trae series..."+ series.toString());
                
                cPagoRepository.actualizaSobrepagoCompPago(regiones, "'"+series+"'");
                
                //LOGGER.info("Que trae series..."+ series.toString());
            }


        } catch (CPagoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Este es mi consulta del properties:

```
 UPDATE COMPLEMENTO_PAGO SET ID_ESTATUS = 1, TIPO_DOCUMENTO= 1, SERIE = NULL WHERE TIPO_DOCUMENTO =4 
       AND ID_ESTATUS =6 AND UUID IS NULL and TO_DATE(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/RRRR') =  
           TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/RRRR')-(select valor from PARAMETROS where ID_PARAMETRO =334) 
       and nom_sistema = Upper((select valor from PARAMETROS where id_parametro =335)) And SERIE in (?)
```

El problema es, como puedo pasarle como parametro al signo de (?) lo que me regresa el metodo `cadenasRegionesAprocesarUpdate` por ejm que me regrese `'PA', 'PB'`? ese problema es el que me trae loco :(

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios en caso de que algo no se entienda, saludos.